# Supervisor unable to run Gunicorn command

Tags: python, nginx, server, gunicorn, supervisord

I have a command which I can successfully run from a directory.

`/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/gunicorn marbles.wsgi:application -b -0.0.0.0:8000 &`

runs from

`/home/ubuntu/Marble/MibsBackEnd/marble-project/marbles/`

and starts my server no problem.

I am trying to get supervisor to run this for me, to keep it alive. Here is my config file

```
[supervisord]
logfile=/tmp/supervisord.log
logfile_maxbytes=50MB

[program:marbles]
command=/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/gunicorn marbles.wsgi:application -b-0.0.0.0:8000 &
directory=/home/ubuntu/Marble/MarbleBackEnd/marble-project/marbles/

[program:test]
command=python -u test.py
directory=/home/ubuntu/Marble/MarbleBackEnd/marble-project/marbles/
```

When supervisor starts up, I get this error

`BACKOFF   Exited too quickly (process log may have details)`

and the log files print this

```
2018-11-09 02:51:29,051 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2018-11-09 02:51:29,051 INFO Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/marbles.conf" during parsing
2018-11-09 02:51:29,058 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2018-11-09 02:51:29,058 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2018-11-09 02:51:29,058 INFO supervisord started with pid 21985
2018-11-09 02:51:30,060 INFO spawned: 'test' with pid 22012
2018-11-09 02:51:30,062 INFO spawned: 'marbles' with pid 22013
2018-11-09 02:51:30,074 INFO exited: marbles (exit status 1; not expected)
2018-11-09 02:51:31,076 INFO success: test entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2018-11-09 02:51:31,077 INFO spawned: 'marbles' with pid 22014
2018-11-09 02:51:31,090 INFO exited: marbles (exit status 1; not expected)
2018-11-09 02:51:33,091 INFO spawned: 'marbles' with pid 22017
2018-11-09 02:51:33,103 INFO exited: marbles (exit status 1; not expected)
2018-11-09 02:51:36,639 INFO spawned: 'marbles' with pid 22021
2018-11-09 02:51:36,652 INFO exited: marbles (exit status 1; not expected)
2018-11-09 02:51:37,048 INFO gave up: marbles entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
2018-11-09 02:53:57,467 INFO waiting for test to die
```

There is a test file that is in the same location, and supervisor can start it no problem. That file just prints to the screen. 
I believe the problem is related to the kind of gunicorn command I am trying to run, but it doesn't work after searching through all other answers.

Help is appreciated!

EDIT:

Here is the gunicorn log file:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/gunicorn", line 7, in <module>
  from gunicorn.app.wsgiapp import run
ImportError: No module named gunicorn.app.wsgiapp`

Comment: When I see this kind of log from wsgi, it's usually because the config needs tweaking to make sure it can find the application... can you post the gunicorn log as well? That's likely to be more informative. Also, it's almost universally better to run these things as a non-root user.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I edited my original question and added that gunicorn log file you requested.

Comment: Well that's interesting. Are you sure your dependencies are all correctly installed? Can you try running gunicorn's tests to make sure it's working in general?